# Get exit status from Pipe contained in brackets

Tags: bash, dd, pipe, zenity

How do I get the exit status of a command in a pipe contained in brackets:

```
(bzcat File_Here | pv -n --size "Size_in_Bytes" | dd of=/dev/sdX) 2>&1
| zenity --title="SD Utility - Write" --progress --text="Writing to SD
Card, This Will take a While" --percentage=0 --no-cancel --auto-close
```

How do I link the exit status of dd to a variable?
It is for error reporting, this script that I have shows successful regardless of errors or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe `-o pipefail` can help you, it will propagate any non-zero exit code through a chain of pipes.

articles about pipefail:

- http://blog.kablamo.org/2015/11/08/bash-tricks-eux/
- http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: Where would I add that in? I am relatively new to bash

Comment: if you are in a script, you can add it at the top as described in the second link. if you are in an interactive prompt, you can execute it before running your real command.